# Correct filename for new file types inside ftdetect folder for vim

Tags: vim

I am creating a new filetype for arduino files in vim.

I looked into the [ftdetect documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#new-filetype) and it is specified that a new file with the following content inside the `.vim/ftdetect/` folder should be created

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.mine        set filetype=mine
```

In the above example both the file extension and filetype are same and the file is created with the name `mine.vim`

But for arduino the file extension (`.ino` and `pde`) is different from the filetype (`arduino`)

My question is what should be the filename in this case. Should it be `ino` or `arduino`?

Comment: It should be `.ino` *and* `.pde`.

Comment: @romainl do you mean I should create two separate files one for each extension?

Comment: Sorry, I was busy elsewhere. Follow Nikita's answer, that's how you do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The filename should be the same as the filetype, i.e. `arduino.vim` in this case. In order to recognize both file extensions, list them as follows:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.ino,*.pde set filetype=arduino
```